# Обработка пакетов асинхронного tcp клиент-сервера

Tags: пакет, обработка, клиент-сервер, асинхронность, сервер

Здравствуйте.

Использовал код с одного из топиков для создания асинхронного сервера и имею следующую проблему: 
Клиент посылает серверу 2 подряд запроса, запросы, надо сказать, очень похожи, и очень часто функция ReadFromStreamAsync читает их, как один запрос из двух склеенных пакетов, соответственно сервер отвечает лишь на один запрос, второй ответ клиент не получает.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, как это исправить.

```
private static async void StartListener()
{
     int counter = 0;
     var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 42129);
     tcpListener.Start();
     while (!exitnow)
     {
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
         processClient(counter, tcpClient);
         counter++;
     }
}
private static async Task processClient(int counter, TcpClient tcpClient)
{
   using (var player = new Player.PlayerInfo(counter, tcpClient, tcpClient.GetStream()))
   {
       try
       {
           Player.AllPlayers.Add(player);
           while (!exitnow)
           {
               await client.ProcessAsync(player);
           }
        }
        finally
        {
            MarkServerplayerAsInactive(player);
            RemovegamebyID(player.ID);
            Player.AllPlayers.Remove(player);
        }
   }
}
async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(int nbytes)
{
     try
     {
          var buf = new byte[nbytes];
          MemoryStream res = new MemoryStream();
          clientstream.ReadTimeout = Config.RWTimeout;
          var bytesRead = await clientstream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
          res.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
          return res.ToArray();
     }
 }
```